# Appium test login in browser and back to app

Tags: java, android, mobile, appium

Im trying to test a Facebook login in my app. When I click the botton for Facebook login my app opens a Chrome browser with the Facebook login on it like this:

[image]

This is not the Google Chrome opening this is still the same app but when I do

```
        System.out.println(driver.getContext());
        Set<String> con = driver.getContextHandles();
        for(String c : con)
        {
            System.out.println("Available Context : "+c);
        }
```

To get the context I only get the NATIVE APP context no WEBVIEW context

Is there a solution to get to the email and password inputs and interact with them?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch context to webview 
Check these appium docs [set-context](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/)
[Automating hybrid apps](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/54c2b4e6500eddbca4bb3047116ceb8d177f7294/docs/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid.md)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Thread.sleep(5000) before driver.getContext() command and check if it outputs the WebView context. If not,
2. Check with the developer of the app and confirm if setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled is set to true in the code.
   Refer this: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/54c2b4e6500eddbca4bb3047116ceb8d177f7294/docs/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid.md#automating-hybrid-android-apps
3. If still no WebView available, you can load the app in the Appium Inspector and try to inspect the elements in the Native mode. In this situation, you won't need to switch the driver context. You can use the native locators like resource-id, accessibility id, etc. as long as those are available in the XML.
4. If the Webview is available, then switch the driver context to Webview using the driver.context("enter_the_webview_name") command and then interact with the UI elements in the WebView mode i.e. using the WebView locators like css, etc.
5. My recommendation is, please avoid automating login on production version of Facebook. It may be blocking bots like Appium. Instead, use Facebook's developer environment and integrate your app with it. Then, automate the facebook login using the test accounts created in the developer environment.